# Assign non identity sequence to field based on another column on multiple row insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have an SQL table in SQL Server 2008 which for this purpose includes Patient_id (Primary), Custno (Char), Recip_Id (Int)

```
1 - C01731 -    1  
2 - C01731 -    2  
3 - C01731 -    3  
4 - C01732 -    1  
5 - C01732 -    2  
6 - C01732 -    3  
7 - C01732 -    4  
8 - C01733 -    1  
9 - C01733 -    2
```

So when I need to insert only a single record I use this stored procedure...

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[JR_SP_NW_InsertRecord]  
(  
    @custno varchar(MAX),  
    @modwho varchar(MAX)  
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
--Declare @retval int  
Declare @rownum int  

SET @rownum = (select MAX(recip_id)+1 From UsersMailingData where custno = @custno)  

    INSERT INTO dbo.UsersMailingData(custno,Recip_id,modify, modifywho)
    Values(@custno, @rownum, GETDATE(), @modwho)  

    select Cast(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)  
END
```

My problem is I need a stored procedure that will look at the highest number in the column Recip_Id based on @custno and then on Insert of multiple rows will increment this number by 1 each row that is inserted.  The recip_id can also have gaps from when records are deleted that is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your problem is that you're inserting rows with select statement, in that case you can use row_number() to assign number to the rows, with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.UsersMailingData(custno,Recip_id,...)
select @custno, row_number() over (order by colname) + @rownum ...
from tablename
```

The colname is a column in which order you want the numbers to be calculated for the new rows.

Your @rownum fetch has also a bug, it doesn't work when there are no rows for the customer.

Comment: How would I do this if I was using an UPDATE command instead of an insert.  I also have to be able to move records where I am updating the customer number.?

Comment: @JRoy Update should the same thing, at least if you want just to add new items to the end of existing ones. If you need to re-number everything it might get more complex.